# NoMethodError in Statuses#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm currently building this website in college for fun. My hope is that it will help the education system. Anyways, I'm still trying to figure out rails. I just set up the devise gem with no problem. ***However, when I click post a new status it gives me this error:***

```
NoMethodError in Statuses#new

Showing /Users/wyatt/Network/netbook/app/views/statuses/_form.html.erb where line #16 raised:

undefined method `user_name' for #<Status:0x00000101ec36d0>
Extracted source (around line #16):

13: 
14:   <div class="field">
15:     <%= f.label :user_name %><br />
16:     <%= f.text_field :user_name %>
17:   </div>
18:   <div class="field">
19:     <%= f.label :content %><br />
```

So here's what ***my form*** looks like:

```
  <%= form_for(@status) do |f| %>
 <% if @status.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@status.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this status from being    saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @status.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
 <% end %>

   <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :user_name %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :user_name %>
  </div>
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :content %><br />
<%= f.text_area :content %>
 </div>
 <div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
 <% end %>
```

***Here's my controller***

```
  class StatusesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /statuses
  # GET /statuses.json
  def index
    @statuses = Status.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @statuses }
    end
  end

  # GET /statuses/1
  # GET /statuses/1.json
  def show
    @status = Status.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @status }
    end
  end

  # GET /statuses/new
  # GET /statuses/new.json
  def new
    @status = Status.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @status }
    end
  end

  # GET /statuses/1/edit
  def edit
    @status = Status.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /statuses
  # POST /statuses.json
  def create
    @status = Status.new(params[:status])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @status.save
        format.html { redirect_to @status, notice: 'Status was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @status, status: :created, location: @status }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @status.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /statuses/1
  # PUT /statuses/1.json
  def update
    @status = Status.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @status.update_attributes(params[:status])
        format.html { redirect_to @status, notice: 'Status was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @status.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /statuses/1
  # DELETE /statuses/1.json
  def destroy
    @status = Status.find(params[:id])
    @status.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to statuses_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you created 'user_name' column in database? Have you run migrations?

Comment: Could you show us the `Status` model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at it, it seems you're wanting to append a `user_name` to a `status`

**Error**

Your error basically means you don't have a `user_name` column in your `statuses` data table. The basic fix will be to create a migration to add a `user_name` column to your `statuses` db:

```
$ rails generate migration AddUserNameToStatuses

#db/migrations/AddUserNameToStatuses.rb
class AddUserNameToStatuses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
      add_column :statuses, :user_name, :string
  end
end

$ rake db:migrate
```

---

**Fix**

I would actually ditch that, and do this:

```
#app/models/status.rb
Class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user #-> you need user_id column in statuses db
    delegate :name, to: :user, prefix: true
end

#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :statuses
end
```

This will allow you to remove the references to `user_name` from your form - as any @status will be associated with a `user`

You'd then be able to use the `.delegate()` method to call `user_name` in `statuses`